# In cytoscape.js, how to apply different style for source/target labels on edge?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have both source and target labels on an edge, I'd like to give the source label an outline (the outline color is computed based on the node property). I see there's "text-outline-color" in style, but it applies to both labels. Is there a way to specify this to only the source labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Labels are styled per-element.  You may specify different text for source and target labels, but they must share the same style.

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels